# How to keep debug code from costing you runtime performance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, preprocessor

I have some timing sensitive asynchronous code that can only be debugged by logging real-time data and then looking at the logs.  As such, I've instrumented the code with statements like this:

```
DBG(`Setting ${name} timer for ${amount} ms from runMore(${reason})`);
```

where `DBG()` has an implementation like this:

```
let debugOn = process.env["DEBUG_RATE_LIMIT_MAP"] === "1";
let DBG;
if (debugOn) {
    DBG = function(...args) {
        args.unshift(time() + ": ");
        console.log(...args);
    }
} else {
    DBG = function() {};
}
```

The general idea is that it only outputs to the console if an environment variable is set.

This all works fine, but it bothers me that even though it doesn't output to the console when the environment variable is not set, it still evaluates the arguments to all the debug statements such as:

```
DBG(`Setting ${name} timer for ${amount} ms from runMore(${reason})`);
```

So, it's still doing throw away work for every statement (evaluating the template strings).  Obviously, Javascript isn't a preprocessed language like C++ where you could "compile out" the debug code.  What techniques are there in Javascript where you can leave debug code in your code base (for future times when you need to do debugging), but not have it detract from run-time performance when debugging is not being used?

For any additional code reference, the entire module is here: https://github.com/jfriend00/async-utils/blob/master/rateMap.js.

Comment: If you use any kind of build chain, JS is as good as any preprocessed language - it's just compiled to (different) JS. There are transpiler plugins to remove debug statements from code.

Comment: @Bergi - Not currently using a build chain.  Also, don't really want the code removed because then you'd have to get a debug version in order to do debugging.  So, maybe my C++ analogy was a bad one because that isn't really what I want.  I was hoping for some run-time scheme with less real-time cost.

Comment: Ah ok. For that, the only thing I could think of would be using a tagged template literal so that you can avoid the string concatenation. (Not certain about its overhead though, you'd need to benchmark).

Comment: @Bergi - I've never really understood a common use for tagged literals.  Maybe this is one possibility, though the template literal is still parsed before calling the tag function, it just hasn't produced the full output yet.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need DBG to be a `function` at all times? If not, you can do:

```
let debugOn = process.env["DEBUG_RATE_LIMIT_MAP"] === "1";
let DBG;
if (debugOn) {
    DBG = function(...args) {
        args.unshift(time() + ": ");
        console.log(...args);
    }
}
```

Then in your code, rather than calling `DBG` directly, you check if it's a function:

```
if (typeof DBG === "function") {
    DBG(`Setting ${name} timer for ${amount} ms from runMore(${reason})`);
}
```

This way, you do have overhead of an `if` condition check but avoid the string literal from ever executing in a production environment.

Comment: Yes, that prevents the extra template evaluation, but it's kind of a pain to sprinkle all through your code.  I was hoping for something cleaner.  And, in this specific example, I could just use `if (debugOn)...`.

Comment: If you use typescript, you could do `DBG?.(stringLiteral)` and that would be much cleaner.
Latest ES would have it as well:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Would the `DBG?.(templateLiteral)` avoid evaluating the templateLiteral if DBG was not defined?  This sounds potentially interesting.

Comment: It should. As the doc mentions it would short-circuit at `DBG` itself. It's equivalent to `DBG && DBG(templateLiteral)`

Comment: So, `DBG && DBG(templateLiteral)` might be just fine now too.

Comment: It is fine but an `if` condition is better in terms of readability unless you're assigning the return value to some variable.
https://www.codereadability.com/dont-use-short-circuiting-when-you-want-an-if-statement/

Answer (score 0):

Based on some comments, my current best idea is this:

```
// environment variable that turns debug tracing on
let debugOn = process.env["DEBUG_RATE_MAP"] === "1";

function DBG(...args) {
    if (debugOn) {
        args.unshift(time() + ": ");
        console.log(...args);
    }
}
```

And, then in the code doing this:

```
if (debugOn) DBG(`Setting ${name} timer for ${amount} ms from runMore(${reason})`);
```

And, if it's just a plain string literal (so no template evaluation to avoid), I can just do this:

```
DBG('All done.');
```

Comment: Another thing: make that a `const debugOn = …`. That way, an optimising compiler could infer that a `false` value won't change, and can completely remove the `if` block.

Comment: @Bergi - I made a conscious choice to use `let` so I could programmatically change the value when debugging if needed.  Good thing to know about the optimization though.